# Applications to the Van der Pol equation?

Tags: oscillators, non-linear-systems

What are some applications to the [Van der Pol equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator)? Are there any physical examples?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what this equation is in the question? From the answer you have got I see that it is interesting. But one should see from reading only the question, that the issue is legitimate and the closevotes it has are not justified... So please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Extracts from this [ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1658)

"Since its introduction in the 1920’s, the Van der Pol equation has been a
prototype for systems with self-excited limit cycle oscillations. The classical
experimental setup of the system is the oscillator with vacuum triode. The
investigations of the forced Van der Pol oscillator behaviour have carried out by
many researchers. The equation has been studied over wide parameter regimes,
from perturbations of harmonic motion to relaxation oscillations. It was much
attention dedicated to investigations of the peculiarities of the Van der Pol
oscillator behaviour under external periodic (sinusoidal) force and, in particular,
the synchronization phenomena and the dynamical chaos appearing . The Van der Pol equation is now concerned as a basic model for
oscillatory processes in physics, electronics, biology, neurology, sociology and
economics . Van der Pol himself built a number of electronic circuit models
of the human heart to study the range of stability of heart dynamics. His
investigations with adding an external driving signal were analogous to the
situation in which a real heart is driven by a pacemaker. He was interested in
finding out, using his entrainment work, how to stabilize a heart's irregular
beating or "arrhythmias". Since then it has been used by scientists to model a
variety of physical and biological phenomena. For instance, in biology, the van
der Pol equation has been used as the basis of a model of coupled neurons in the
gastric mill circuit of the stomatogastric ganglion .
The Fitzhugh–Nagumo equation is a planar vector field that extends the van der
Pol equation as a model for action potentials of neurons. In seismology, the van
der Pol equation has been used in the development a model of the interaction of
two plates in a geological fault" .

Comment: Minor comment to the answer (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1658